# How to get friendlist from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to get friend list from Facebook but i am not able to get friend list. I tried out different code but i always get null in response. Even if i run sample like scrumptious app i also don't get the friend list. Someone suggest me to use `"me/taggable_friends"` but still not getting friend list.

So i really want to know whether it is possible to get friend list from Facebook. If yes then please show me the way.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback(){

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                requestMyAppFacebookFriends(session);

            }

        });


      }

      private Request createRequest(Session session) {
            Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/taggable_friends", null);

            Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
            String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture"};
            fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

            Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
            parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
            request.setParameters(parameters);

            return request;
        }


      private void requestMyAppFacebookFriends(Session session) {
            Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
            friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    List<GraphUser> friends = getResults(response);

                   Log.v(TAG, "friends list size "+friends.size());
                }
            });
            friendsRequest.executeAsync();
        }

      private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
            GraphMultiResult multiResult = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
            GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
            return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
        }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, but you have to explain this *don't get*? The api is `/me/taggable_friends` but pls elaborate so that we may help you. Which API version you using and other details. At least show some piece of code too

Comment: I mean i don't get the frinedlist list even if i run the sample code from facebookSDK samples. Acutally i want to get displaypicture, name, id of all my facebook friends and show them in list or grid view. I am using 3.15.0 version of sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has made some significant changes in 2.0 version. One of the change is to get the friends list. Previously we were able to obtain the friendslist with `/me/friends` but this endpoint doesn't work with v2.0.

You've used the correct API— `/me/taggable_friends`, but the thing is that this needs to be reviewed by facebook first to use this in you live app. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) is explained how to submit for the review.

For testing purpose, switch your app to development mode or test the app with developers/admins/testers account only; else you'll get a blank response.

Comment: but i only want to access profile_picture, email_id, friendlsit for these you don't need login review.

Comment: You need the details of the friends right? So yes you need the review. I dont know how else to convince you

Comment: i have created the test app but i ma still getting null in response

Comment: In simple words- this isnt possible. Check the reponse in Graph API Explorer

Comment: "only email"? you will not get the emails of the user friends in ANY case, this would be a major privacy issue. just in case you want to do that. for the email of the authorized user, you have to use the email permission.